# Weird jumping of loss function - underfitting?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, object-detection

this is my first question here if i am doing something wrong please be patient with me.

In my free time i like to experiment with neural networks, especially with object detection NN's. I followed  [this tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) which uses the faster rcnn-v2 (pretrained) and for the provided test files in the tutorial the training went fine and the object detector worked as well.

I then changed to my own pictures and tried to adapt the steps. But whe the training starts after a few steps my loss starts jumping (as you can see in the picture) [jumping loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG0wf.jpg) and [here are the tensorboard records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYUiK.jpg). I made this picture after a few thousand steps but nothing changes later. I once trained it up to 80.000 steps and I still had jumping loss.

I train my network to detect relatively small objects in large pictures so maybe there might be problem? I would like to train it on the detection of music notes. I started with only two objects [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ5V6.jpg) for test purposes to see if it even works. The images have a resolution of around 2500 x 1500.

I have around 170 labelled images for training with about 10 objects of each class in the images and 30 pictures for testing.

Since that didn't work I tried to train with only one image for test and train to provoke overfitting to see that the model itself can handle this but the loss also started jumping.

So where might the error be? I am afraid that this neural network is the wrong one for this kind of object detection...

PS: Don't know if this is important i use paperspace for training the network.

Comment: What is the accuracy that you are getting for the test samples? The jumping in loss is not much fluctuating, so it is not a big issue. And loss jumping will never reach zero fluctuations.

Comment: But have you seen that the loss varies from .4 to 10^15? This cant't be true. Unfortunately in this toutorial there is no accuracy function implemented. But when I test it. It detects nothing. So I'm a little bit desperate since I don't know where even this error could come from...